Can't reach ubuntu's official website from my home wifi but, I can on mobile data
I am connected to my home wifi network and tried to go to ubuntu.com from my browser. The website is not responding. I also tried on my mobile phone on the same network, same problem.
But, When I switch to mobile data it works.

This is not a Ubuntu bug. Please contact your internet service provider
